# Serial Communication in C# using arduino, android, winform

Tags: c#, android, winforms, serial-port

I have a program that is similar to an ATM application. I use my android device a the Keypad. No problem with transmitting data from phone to my C# program. I use threading. I have a problem on how to really "start" the ATM application.

The only input device is the android device. I will not use computer keyboard or anything. So once the program is shown, the first thing is that the program will ask what kind of transaction is it.

```
private void FrontPage_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ask_Transaction(); 
}
```

and inside that... (Edited part)

```
public void Ask_Transaction()
    {
        string decoded_input = "";

        decoded_input = KT.CheckPress(input); //"input" is the data from the arduino. the checkpress will decode it.

        do
        {
            try
            {
                //input = serialPort.ReadLine();

                switch (KT.CheckPress(input))
                {
                    case "S5": //Card;
                        break;
                    case "S6": //Cardless
                        {
                            PF.Format_Cardless(); 
                            AskLanguage(); //if cardless, it will now ask the language. Once again, another input from serial is needed
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Cancel": PF.Format_TransactionCancelled();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //To catch ReadTimeout after 6 seconds
                //"You do not respond to the alloted time.."
            }
        }
        while (decoded_input != "S5"
            || decoded_input != "S6"
            || decoded_input != "Cancel");

    }
```

my problem is that when I try to loop Ask_Transaction until I get the correct inputs (S5 or S6 or cancel) using a do-while loop, my program is lagging and eventually crashing. No errors displaying.

EDIT:
Of course we cannot assure that the user will input the correct key. And usually when you click just numbers on the keypad, ATM program will not notify you at first. It will just wait for possible correct inputs. Also, if the user enters S6, the program will now ask another input using those keypad numbers s5 and s6. the problem is that the program is not "continuous". Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the loop? Did you try to simply add a short (50 msec) delay between each polling test?

Comment: Is it lagging/crashing because of a StackOverflowException? Are you continuously creating instances of an object that you're not releasing? Also, I reckon the loop should be running in a thread (can't see how it's implemented here.)

Comment: I edited the part. :) please help.. specially with the "continuous" part and with looping.

Comment: @Adriano Yes I add delay. Another reinstatement of my problem is how can I ask inputs from user and go to another module then ask again? Also, is it correct that I put the Ask_Transaction on the Form_Shown?

Comment: It depends what you mean with "module". Form? About polling I would do it in a BackgroundWorker so it won't freeze your UI while checking for response.